Distribution Evaluation for SAA
I understand that Sample Average Approximation (SAA) in optimization is considered as an approximation model using the law of large numbers (such as in this link). Therefore the approximation of the lower bound and upper bound is developed based on the Normal distribution's calculation of the average. Meanwhile, the note for applying SAA in stochastic models doesn't mention the requisite distribution of the stochastic variables.
I wonder if any suggestions are available for me to check my above understanding and whether it is necessary to ensure the normality of the stochastic input?

Not sure I understand your question correctly. Are you asking whether the random variables need to be normally distributed for SAA to work? If that is your question, then the answer is no.

Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Thank you, @batwing. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Does it mean that the law of large numbers is not entangled with a particular distribution?

Are you conflating the Law of Large Numbers with the Central Limit Theorem?  The former is not limited to Gaussian (Normal) distributions.

Humn.... the SAA is surely stated to be based on the law of large numbers, but the calculation of LB and UB uses the t-value and z-value. Therefore, I am a little bit confused.

A large number of results in SAA relies on the applicability of Law of large numbers (LLW). LLW by itself does not require the stochastic variables to be normal or come from some other specific distribution, but there are other conditions needed for LLW to be applicable. Some aspects of these seem to be covered in this paper.

Distribution (discrete or continuous)) of random variables is approximated using machine learning/Bayesian techniques on historical data. In stochastic programming you also have multi-stage model with recourse variables that are adjusted based on realization if the distribution estimated in preceding stages.
